# Add script to progress bar

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, web-services

HTML/JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
        var tout, service;
        function UpdateStatus()
        {
            if (tout !== null)
                clearTimeout(tout);
            if (service === null)
                service = new namespace.progressbar.GetStatus();
            service.GetStatus(onSuccess, onFailure);
        }

        function onSuccess(result) {
            PROGRE.style.width = percent + "%";
            tout = setTimeout("UpdateStatus()", 1000);
        }

        function onFailure(error) {
            alert(error.get_message());
        }
</script>

<div class="progress" >
    <div class="progress-bar" id="progressBar" runat="server" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:20%" >
        <asp:Label ID="Label5" Font-Bold="true" runat="server" Text="20%"></asp:Label>    
        <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="ScriptManager">
            <Services>
                <asp:ServiceReference Path="~/ProgressBar.asmx" InlineScript="false" />
            </Services>                           
        </asp:ScriptManager>
    </div>
</div>
```

Web Service:

```
public int GetStatus()
    {
        int progress = 0; 

        return progress;
    }
```

I'm trying to check every some seconds if some updates were made on my page and to update the progress bar.
I don't understand how to link the JavaScript with the web service:

The way I think this should work is like this:  call every some time JavaScript, JavaScript will call and get the result from my web service and then JavaScript will update my progress bar.

Did I miss something?